# Timeline view of Process call stack profiling

Tags: process, perf

I have a process for which I need to do profiling on.

Have used perf on linux which provides a snapshot of calls stacks occuring within a time interval, However I cant figure out the chronology of events and the call stack.

For example:

Say an interesting event(to me) E(i) causes process to produce fx->fy->fk call stack but exactly when in time did this call stack happened is what I am unable to deduce.

So then it is good to known the frequency of each of the call stacks, for my analysis I need the timeline as I know when E(i) trigger happeneded. Hence wondering if there was a such tool which could provide a correlation of call stacks to their time of occurences.

Comment: https://www.speedscope.app/ web app can visualize perf.data files into timeline and focus into time region. `perf script` will parse perf.data and show internal timestamps and all profiling events (samples). But perf profiling will not show you exact call count. You may also check tracing (perf, trace-cmd or any other variant) to get timestamps and exact call counts.

Comment: So how is this different from flamegraph tool? I know it says it is an inspiration from flamegraph but can it provide the heap map allong with the timeline? Left view?

Comment: speedscope is interactive and may be easier to use when you want to focus on some parts of timeline. For the events add uprobes and add this uprobe event to `perf record`'s event list.